Where is Tkinter sourcing info about the screen DPI?
Using X on Linux, Tkinter (Python 3.12) tells me that I have a DPI value of ~96 (wrong), while the X server tells me that my DPI value is ~185 (correct).
In [1]: import tkinter as tk
   ...: root = tk.Tk()
   ...: print(root.winfo_fpixels('1i'))
   ...: root.destroy()
   ...: 
   ...: xrandr_out = ! xrandr
   ...: xy_in = [int(mm[:-2])/25.4 for mm in xrandr_out[1][-13:].split(' x ')]
   ...: xy_pix = [int(pixels) for pixels in xrandr_out[2].split()[0].split('x')]
   ...: dpi_x, dpi_y = [pixels/dimension for pixels, dimension in zip(xy_pix, xy_in)]
   ...: print(dpi_x, dpi_y)
   ...: 
96.08406304728547
185.35135135135135 185.66497461928932

In [2]: 

(I'm sorry for the convoluted way of finding the real DPI value, it is possible that you have to adjust my code to make it work on your distribution.)
Where does Tkinter find the incorrect information regarding the DPI value?

Are you, by chance, using any sort of display scaling?

@Sam ________ No

I ask because I suspect tk is querying the OS for a default dpi, irrespective of any other factors. For example, the same call on my Win10 system will also return 96, which is, coincidentally, the default dpi used by Windows. I have my display scaled by 125%, making my "effective" dpi 120. There's an easy workaround in Windows with the ctypes module by forcing dpi awareness for the running process before instantiating tk, which will make the same call return the correct value of 120. Note this is entirely speculative and I have no idea if there is an equivalent workaround for Linux,

@sam I never understood the DPI default crap, it's at least 20 years that any device can report its physical dimensions...

Again, speculation, but I would assume a reason for a default dpi is so the OS has a "de facto" standard to fall back on if/when there's an issue retrieving specific info from the connected display (missing drivers, e.g.). Why OSes or any other software would utilize these defaults for any other reason, I have no idea. I was just speculating on the "where" in your question, no idea on the "why".
